# doInBackground run so fast when using AsyncTask in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a problem so strange when using `Asynctask` in `fragment`,

In `onCreate` of `Fragment` I called `AsyncTask` like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Step 1 
    new FitnessHistoryDataAsync(getActivity()).execute(10);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and the `doInBackground` method:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    // Step 2 
    Log.i("", "doInBackground");

    Constants.SDK.getFitnessHistoryData(context, 10,
            new FitnessHistoryListener() {

        @Override
        public void onReceiveFailed(String errorMessage) {
             // Step 4 
            Log.i("", "error " + errorMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceiveData(
                FitnessHistory[] fitnessHistoryData) {
            // Step 4 
            Log.i("", "onReceiveData");
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

and the `onPostExecute` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // Step 3 
    Log.i("", "onPostExecute");

            // Hide progress bar dialog
    Constants.connectivity.hideProgressDialog();
}
```

My `Asynctask` ran as followed: `Step 1`, `Step 2`, `Step 3`, then `Step 4`.

The problem is in the `doInBackground` method where `Step 2` and `Step 4` cannot run at the same time before running `Step 3` in the `onPostExecute` method.

I want everything in the `doInBackground` method to run before going to the `onPostExecute` method.

Please help me.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

I changed to the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Step 1 
    new FitnessHistoryDataAsync(getActivity()).executeonExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, 10);
}
```

Although I used `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` or `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` to try to fix this problem, but cannot.

Comment: what dose Constants.SDK.getFitnessHistoryData really do? dose it run on another thread?

Comment: @AbolhassanAbdolalizade : I don't know since it is the library I used. If it is the another thread. How I can fix this problem guy? Help me please.

Comment: It looks like the `onReceiveFailed` and `onReceiveData` are asynchronous callbacks triggered by getFitnessHistoryData.  If this is the case, you may not need to use an AsyncTask for this.  Just call `getFitnessHistoryData`, and put the `onPostExecute` code in those callbacks.  Please note that you will probably have to post any code that touches the UI to the main thread.

Comment: @Velox : I tried. Put all codes into `onPostExecute` method. But The life cycle as I said in this post still be same. `touches the UI to the main thread` - It still reach the UI before completed Background thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the library I used also is another thread.
So, I no need to create new thread `AsyncTask`.

Just edit coding like this :

```
Constants.SDK.getFitnessHistoryData(context, 10,
        new FitnessHistoryListener() {

    @Override
    public void onReceiveFailed(String errorMessage) {
         // Step 4 
        Log.i("", "error " + errorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveData(
            FitnessHistory[] fitnessHistoryData) {
        // Step 4 
        Log.i("", "onReceiveData");

        // TODO Directly updated UI in here when already received new data
    }
});
```

That's solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `new FitnessHistoryDataAsync(getActivity()).execute(10);` before  `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` is a problem you should fix first.
 Change it to something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Step 1 
    new FitnessHistoryDataAsync(getActivity()).execute(10);

}
```

Comment: Hello, I already changed the coding like yours, but can not fix my problem.